# Installing Node Causes Windows 10 Machine to Repeatedly Restart

Tags: windows-10, node.js, chocolatey

I've installed NodeJS, the Current (not LTS) version on my Windows 10 system. That seems to have installed at least a couple additional things along with it, namely *Chocolatey* and *BoxStarter*.

Since then, my system is continually restarting. It opens a command window that says something like *Boxstarter is installing Chocolatey*, then keeps installing things (per console messages, things like *visualstudio*, *vbtools*, *vcredist140-x86* and *-x64*, etc.) and restarting. Is this expected behavior?

By the way, I must have had this *Automatically install...* option checked during the Node JS install:

### [image]

Answer (score 2):

First off, immediately ctrl + c to kill the process when it starts firing in cmd/powershell to prevent a reboot.

Then launch "Startup Tasks" from windows start menu and toggle off "boxstarter-post-restart.bat"

Comment: There is a discussion on this, along with fixes and future plans - maybe link that as well?